# How can I determine the elements in an array that do not exist in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

In Ruby I can do this:

```
fruit = ['banana','apple','tangerine','orange','lemon','lime','kiwi','mango','guava']
citrus = ['orange','lemon','lime','tangerine']
others = fruit - citrus
```

And `others` will contain an array of non-citrus fruits.

How can I do this in PHP?

```
$fruit = array('banana','apple','tangerine','orange','lemon','lime','kiwi','mango','guava');
$citrus = array('orange','lemon','lime','tangerine');
$others = # NOW WHAT ?????
```

Do I need to iterate over each item in `$citrus` and find its offset in `$fruit` (if it exists in that array) and then unset it, and then use array_values() to fix the array's indices?  Or is there a simpler, less error-prone way?

**Please note:** I'm *not* looking for the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of the arrays. I'm looking for a [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29). This was originally closed as a duplicate of a question asking the former.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Perhaps from the same people who mistakenly closed the question?

Comment: Are the downvotes from people who didn't take the time to understand the question, and in their ignorance closed it, or from angry PHP developers who want to punish anyone who mentions Ruby?  Either way they are totally unjustified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) which does exactly that:

```
 $others = array_diff($fruit, $citrus);
```

That'll leave you with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [6] => kiwi
    [7] => mango
    [8] => guava
)
```

Which seems to be the expected remainder after subtracting citrus fruits from other fruits.

Comment: Your answer and Baba's answer were equally good, and came in a second apart.  Yours was one second earlier, and gave me a link... I'm not sure that's the perfect criteria to decide who to award credit to, but I don't have any better criteria.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `array_diff`

```
$fruit = array('banana','apple','tangerine','orange','lemon','lime','kiwi','mango','guava');
$citrus = array('orange','lemon','lime','tangerine');
$others = array_diff($fruit, $citrus);
var_dump($others);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'banana' (length=6)
  1 => string 'apple' (length=5)
  6 => string 'kiwi' (length=4)
  7 => string 'mango' (length=5)
  8 => string 'guava' (length=5)
```

Comment: You're right, it works, despite the name (and documentation!) suggesting it does a DIFF on the arrays.  In fact it does exactly what you say.  If I [change $citrus to include 'clementine'](http://codepad.org/9bUixf9z), it still does what I want.  I would expect a *diff* to somehow mention *that* difference as well.  This function would be better named `array_subtraction` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) :

```
 $others = array_merge(array_diff($fruit, $citrus));
```

You would need to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to arrange the indices. See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/CyWD5zqF)

`$others` will contain these values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [6] => kiwi
    [7] => mango
    [8] => guava
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by  [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);


$result = array_intersect($parts1 , $parts2 );
print_r($result);
```

[**Live Example**](http://codepad.org/DXNBHuZY)

> [image]

and

```
$result = array_diff($parts1 , $parts2 );

print_r($result);
```

[**LIVE example**](http://codepad.org/DFsPMcCj)

> [image]

Comment: @Baba because it's my answer and i have permission